# Adding a JSON file for domain verification

Tags: azure, dns

I am trying to verify my domain through Azure using this  [Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-configure-publisher-domain#to-verify-a-new-domain-for-your-app). However, it keeps saying it cannot verify. I think maybe it's because I am assuming just putting it in my `wwwroot` is sufficient, but I don't know what else I need to do to have `https://{YOUR-DOMAIN-HERE}.com/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json` open the file itself for verification.

> Verification of publisher domain failed. Unable to connect to https://mydomain/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association. [uFNK6]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Many people have faced this issue, you could have a look at [this1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35934) and [this2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39665) on Github. You may get one-time free support ticket for this issue via

> You could send an email to AzCommunity[at]microsoft[dot]com with a
> reference to this thread and also your Azure Subscription GUID.

As a workaround, you could [add your custom domain to Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain#add-your-custom-domain-name-to-azure-ad). Then verify your custom domain name. After verifying your domain, you could directly `select a verified domain` or `verify a new domain` in the **Publisher Domain** panel without host the file at `https://{YOUR-DOMAIN-HERE}.com/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json`.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: I've added a custom domain and verified it (its verification takes a minute a succeeds instantly), however I cannot select that custom domain as my app is meant to be used by Personnal accounts. Indeed if I publish an app with private company accounts, it works flawlessly, but not with personnal accounts and cannot use both type of account else it will never be allowed by MS.

Comment: For me, it worked and I could choose my app domain https://workstats.dev/ as a Publisher domain on Microsoft Azure Branding & Properties page.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding a *web.config* file to the *.well-known* folder to remove *charset=utf8* from the *Content-Type* response. This [appears to be necessary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-configure-publisher-domain#to-verify-a-new-domain-for-your-app).

Beofre you start you can check with *Curl* from a PowerShell instance to see if the *Content-Type* being returned includes the charset and therefore is the source of your problem.

```
C:> curl https://www.whateveryourdomainis.org/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json
```

The *web.config* file contents is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="MicrosoftIdentityAssociation" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".json" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You need to be aware that this will modify the child folders too and so if you have other sub-folders you may have to take remedial action ie another web.config file putting it back. However, it may be that once you have verified the site, the verification code can be deleted. See `[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/37272/should-we-continue-to-host-microsoft-identity-asso.html][2]`

Comment: OP's issue is about "unable to connect", not about content-type being incorrect. Got the same issue as OP with appropriate content-type (no charset).